# Is this dockerfile set correctly to serve a React.js build on port 5000?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm, dockerfile

I have a React.js app which I have dockerized and it was working fine until yesterday when there was some kind of an error which I found out is due to node version 17 so I decided to get the docker image's node version back to 16. All good, but since I did this, I cannot get the docker image to run on the specified port.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
ROM node:16.10-alpine as build

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY /front-end/dashboard/package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY ./front-end/dashboard /app

RUN npm run build

# Install `serve` to run the application.
RUN npm install -g serve

# Set the command to start the node server.
CMD serve -s -n build

# Tell Docker about the port we'll run on.
EXPOSE 5000
```

As you can see, I am making a build which I then serve on port 5000 but for some reason that does not work anymore and it used to work fine.

All I can see as an output in docker is:

> > Serving!                                     │
>
> │                                                │
>
> │   - Local:            http://localhost:3000    │
>
> │   - On Your Network:  http://172.17.0.2:3000

When I go to localhost:3000 nothing happens which is fine but it should be working on port 5000 and it does not run there. Any idea why I cannot run the docker image's build on port 5000 as I used to do before?

I use docker run -p 5000:5000 to run it on port 5000 but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Well you don't tell which port serve should use and the output tells you it's using 3000, so haven't you got the answer?

Comment: I mention that it needs to be on port 5000 and in the dockerfile I `EXPOSE` it to port 5000 but it does not run on port 5000 which is my problem that I want to solve.

Comment: `EXPOSE 5000` is just _metadata_, do you have any _configuration_? Did you read the docs for serve to see what form that might take?

Comment: Also it's not clear how if at all you're then exposing any ports to the host you're running it on.

Comment: I use docker run -p 5000:5000 but the problem stays.

Comment: Well, again, the output tells you it's not actually running on port 3000 inside the container so that shouldn't be entirely surprising. That's been the default since v13: https://github.com/vercel/serve/commit/168d4b2447366f1012e517ced5a84249020eb1c1.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think you got the root cause. Probably the OP just rebuilt the container using the latest codebase and got surprised by the change in default values.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri I'd guess so, yes; just using an unqualified `npm install -g serve` isn't a good move for reproducible builds!

Comment: Is it just a typo on your question here or is the first line `ROM` instead of `FROM` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced issues at work due to this exact same scenario. After a few hours of looking through our companies deployment pipeline, I discovered the culprit...

The serve package.

They changed the default port from 5000 to 3000.
Source: [serve github releases](https://github.com/vercel/serve/releases/tag/13.0.0)

So, to fix your issue, I recommend to add `-l 5000` in your `serve` cmd.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to figure out that after some time of struggle. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs you can see that your application might be listening for traffic on localhost:3000. Your `EXPOSE 5000` line does not change that behaviour but makes Docker (and other users) think port 5000 is important. Since nothing is listening on port 3000 obviously you should get a 'connection refused'. You may want to lookup https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

To get out of that situation:

- ensure your dockerized process is listening to 0.0.0.0:5000. You will have to add `-l tcp://0.0.0.0:5000`to your CMD line (see https://github.com/vercel/serve/blob/main/bin/serve.js#L117)
- When running the container, ensure you expose the port by using `docker run -p 5000:5000 ...`
- If need be tell your docker host's firewall to allow traffic to <ip>:5000

Now if you connect to http://<ip>:5000 you should see the application's response.

Comment: Yes, I run it with docker run -p 5000:5000 and this is when I get this result.

Comment: As we already pointed out, your application is listening on port 3000. What is the result of  `serve --help` ?

Comment: The thing is that all I have in my dockerfile used to work. I ran it on port 5000 and it worked. I never had this issue. I only changed my node version to 16.10 and this gave me the error. 

Yes, by default it runs on port 3000 but by building a build and then serving it, I can run 5000:5000 as I used to. My issue is to find out why my working code does not work anymore.

Comment: You changed to 16.10 - which version did you have before, and when was your last build? See @jonrsharpe 's comment above. Then add the parameter as I suggested.

Comment: I used this command `node:latest` and it would use the latest version which is 17.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is listening on port 3000. So you need to map whatever port you want to use on the host to port 3000. If you want to use port 5000, you should use `-p 5000:3000`. Then you should be able to access it using `localhost:5000` on the host machine.

You should think of containers as separate machines from the host. So when the container says that it's listening on localhost:3000, that means localhost in the context of the container. Not the host.